# Handsontable saving only 250 rows

Tags: php, jquery, handsontable

I am using handsontable in my application. When i tried to save data, using AJAX and PHP, I am able to get only 250 rows of data. Is there any specific configuration , that i need to change to be able to save all the data from handsontable?I have recently changed my css, does that effect anyway?
Please take a look at the code below.

```
    $("#divButtons").find(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
    url: "saveData3.php",
    data: { "data" : $container.data('handsontable').getData()},
     //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',               
    success: function(){......})};
```

My php

```
  $post_data = $_POST['data'];
 if (!empty($post_data)) {
  $file = fopen('data_save3.json', 'w+');
  fwrite($file, json_encode($post_data));
  fclose($file);
//echo json_encode('success');
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: CSS could very well be at play. Have a look and see if you have any height constraints.

Comment: What version of Handsontable have you used?

Comment: I tried removing all the styles, But still it is saving only 250 rows

Comment: please let me know, if there are any other possibilities. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work! I was using a "next" button to save the handsontable data and also to navigate to the next page..Now, I used "save" and "next" buttons respectively. That solved the problem.